# jQuery UI range slider with staggered upper/lower steps

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, slider, range, uislider

I want to create a [jQuery UI range slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range) where the set of values that the upper bound can be set to is different from the set of values that the lower bound can be set to.  Essentially I want a slider where the range of possible values is [a, b] but the two handles "leapfrog" alternate values, so that the lower handle can only be set to the 1st, 3rd, 5th, etc., values in the range, and the upper handle can only be set to the 2nd, 4th, 6th, etc.

The simplest example would be: is it possible to create a range slider with values 1-10 where the lower handle can only be set to odd numbers and the upper handle can only be set to even numbers?

The use case is I have a slider for selecting time ranges in years.  The lower bound should represent the beginning of a year and the upper bound the end of a year.  So if you set lower bound to 2012 and upper bound also to 2012, this should mean "from beginning of 2012 to end of 2012".

I could make a slider with double the range and do some math to compute the underlying range (i.e., select 2012 for "beginning of 2012" and 2012.5 for "end of 2012" but hide this from the user), but the problem is that then the user could set the end to "beginning of 2012", which I don't want.  The issue is that I actually want the visual UI to prevent the two handles from occupying the same positions, to prevent someone from choosing a range that is semantically invalid for my purposes.

I tried to get clever and use the "step" option while setting the initial upper/lower bounds to staggered values, but this doesn't work.  It seems that the steps are not calculated relative to the current value, but rather the value is "snapped" to available step positions at each move.  So if you have a 1-10 slider where the step size is 2 but the upper bound is set to 10, moving it down one will take it to 9, not 8.  This is exactly what I don't want, because I want the two handles to have different, interleaved available values.

I'm open to solutions that use some widget set other than jQuery UI if that's easier, although I'd prefer a solution based on some reputable widget set.  (That is, I'd rather have something that builds on existing range sliders, not a from-scratch implementation of a slider with this particular feature.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cancel `slide` event by `return false;`.
See [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/jhXLC/3/) on jsfiddle.

```
function setValues(stepIncrease) {
  return function (event, ui) {
    var slider = $("#" + this.id);
    var currentValues = slider.slider("values");
    var step = slider.slider("option")["step"];
    if ((Math.abs(ui.values[0] - currentValues[0]) % (stepIncrease * step) != 0 || Math.abs(ui.values[1] - currentValues[1]) % (stepIncrease * step) != 0)){
        return false;
    };
    slider.slider("values", ui.values);
    var currentValues = slider.slider("values");
    $("#" + this.id + "-values").html(currentValues[0] + ' ' + currentValues[1]);
  };
};
```

And in the slider:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#slider-range-1-2" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 1,
    max: 10,
    step: 1,
    values: [1, 10],
    slide: setValues(2),
    create: function(event, ui) {
        var slider = $("#" + this.id);
        var currentValues = slider.slider("values");
        $("#" + this.id + "-values").html(currentValues[0] + ' ' + currentValues[1]);
    }
  });
});
```

**UPD**
This is function to handle `keydown` events

```
function eventHandlerKeydown(slider, stepIncrease) {
return function(event) {
    var step, curVal, min, max, newVal, index = $( event.target ).data( "ui-slider-handle-index" );
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case $.ui.keyCode.UP:
        case $.ui.keyCode.RIGHT:
        case $.ui.keyCode.DOWN:
        case $.ui.keyCode.LEFT:
            event.preventDefault();
            if ( !slider.keySliding ) {
                slider.keySliding = true;
                $(event.target).addClass( "ui-state-active" );
            }
            break;
    }
    step = slider.slider("option")["step"];
    max = slider.slider("option")["max"];
    min = slider.slider("option")["min"];
    curVal = slider.slider("values")[index];
    switch ( event.keyCode ) {
        case $.ui.keyCode.UP:
        case $.ui.keyCode.RIGHT:
            newVal = curVal + step * stepIncrease;
            if ( newVal > max ) {
                return;
            }
            slider.slider("values", index, newVal );
            break;
        case $.ui.keyCode.DOWN:
        case $.ui.keyCode.LEFT:
            newVal = curVal - step * stepIncrease;
            if ( newVal < min ) {
                return;
            }
            slider.slider("values", index, newVal );
            break;
    }
}
}
```

And in the slider:

```
$(function() {
var slider = $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
    ...
});
var handlers = slider.children("a");
$.each(handlers, function(index, handler) {
    $(handler).off('keydown');
    $(handler).on({keydown: eventHandlerKeydown(slider, 1)});
});
});
```

And the [link to example](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/jhXLC/5/).

*P.S.* I still think there is a easily solution for this.

If You want only choose beginning or end of the years I think @user568109 is right

```
function showValues(event, ui) {
var values;
if (!ui.values) {
    values = $("#" + event.target.id).slider("values");
} else {
    values = ui.values;
}
if (values[0] == values[1]) {
    return false;
} else {
    var periodFrom;
    values[0] % 1 == 0 ? periodFrom = 'beginnig of the year' : periodFrom = 'year-end';
    var periodTo;
    values[1] % 1 == 0 ? periodTo = 'beginnig of the year' : periodTo = 'year-end';
    $("#" + event.target.id + "-values").html('From ' + periodFrom + ' ' + parseInt(values[0]) + '<br />to ' + periodTo + ' ' + parseInt(values[1]));
}
}
$(function() {
$( "#slider" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 2010,
    max: 2013.5,
    step: 0.5,
    values: [2010, 2013.5],
    slide: showValues,
    create: showValues,
    change: showValues
});
});
```

Example [there](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/mhvfW/)

Comment: The problem with that is it seems to make the slider jerky.  Grabbing and dragging sometimes doesn't move the slider to the right position depending on the speed of the drag, even if I'm dragging away from the other handle.  Presumably this is because some of the drag events are being interfered with too early, causing valid slides to be cancelled.

Comment: @BrenBarn, no, it's cause condition allows only 1 slide per mouse move, try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/jhXLC/4/) and see on the `if () {return false};` statement. Before it cancel the event when only `N*step` intervals mouse moves, and now it's slides when mouse moves `K*N*step` intervals.

Comment: This works, but there's still a problem: it doesn't work from the keyboard. Trying to use the arrow keys generates a slide event to move the slider up one step, which is then canceled by the custom handling. I tried to fix this with some hacking by looking at the event type, but it didn't quite work.  I notice your code includes a spurious `slider.slider("values", ui.values)`.  This sets the values, but has no ultimate effect, because after this code runs the default jQuery UI code runs and sets the value again.  Is there any way to re-trigger the slide event with a different target value?

Comment: @BrenBarn yeah, sure you can. jQuery have an [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) methods which bind and unbind events to the elements. You just must reattach `keydown`, `click` and `keyup` events (`_handleEvents` function on 13221 line in [this](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js) file) to the `handles` on slider.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think the idea of having ranges different for upper and lower slider is totally sensible. You are confusing real numbers with date time ranges.

Number 2012 could mean start/end of the year but only for user. It should be clear in the code that it is either the start or the end. Usually it is the start of the year.

So 2012 - 2013 in actual real numbers would translate to beginning of 2012 to beginning of 2013. Or you could simply change the last term as beginning of x to end of x-1.

The only problem here is that you don't want the sliders to overlap. So just check for the values.

```
if (ui.values[ 1 ] === ui.values[ 0 ])
            return false;
```

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipinroshan/gkqsR/).

Comment: Your approach does not allow a slider with 1-10 such that every range, including 1-1 and 10-10, can be selected.  If N on the slider means "beginning of N", then I would have to add an extra value at the end of the slider to represent a year that is not included in the data, just as a placeholder for the beginning of that year.  What I really want, which you're sort of getting at, is I want the slider to have upper and lower handles set to the same value *while still having a visual gap* between the two handles.  However, this would seem even more difficult.

Comment: @BrenBarn Yes, you would have to compensate for allowing 1 unit gap to be counted as 0. So 1-2 is value 1 with 1 gap 10-11 is value 10 with 1 gap. To get 1-10 inclusive you would need 1-11. Now is this so difficult, adding one extra value to your range to adjust so that you get the visual gap and subtracting upper index by 1 to get range value that you would rather have decimal values and steps and compute the underlying range. Why make it so complicated? The range for the slider does not have to be the actual range of values.